# Melhores práticas para armazenar imagens no Amazon S3 e salvar no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, amazon-aws

Estou modelando um banco de dados, porém estou em dúvida como farei para lidar com essa parte de salvar a imagem no Amazon S3 e referenciar de forma fácil no banco de dados.

Pretendo salvar a URL da imagem (hospedado no Amazon S3) em um campo chamado "image_url" do bd.

Uma das duvidas minha é:

Como faço para gerar várias versões de dimensões da imagem (sm, md, lg, original), e conseguir salvar as respectivas url no banco de dados? Devo criar uma coluna para cada versão da imagem? Ex: image_url_sm, image_url_md, image_url_lg, image_url_original. Na minha opinião isso parece uma mal prática de banco de dados.

Aqui esta minha tabela atual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu particularmente tentaria não manter nada disso no banco. Eu criaria um GUID pra cada registro e faria a URL de cada imagem ser derivada desse GUID. Exemplo de um registro:

```
id: 123
name: "Eletrônicos"
image_key: "fdb3a9ba-b5e6-4d56-b703-27adb55c6f92"
etc...
```

No S3 eu criaria e salvaria cada versão da imagem:

- meubucket/categories/images/fdb3a9ba-b5e6-4d56-b703-27adb55c6f92.original.png
- meubucket/categories/images/fdb3a9ba-b5e6-4d56-b703-27adb55c6f92.sm.png
- meubucket/categories/images/fdb3a9ba-b5e6-4d56-b703-27adb55c6f92.md.png
- meubucket/categories/images/fdb3a9ba-b5e6-4d56-b703-27adb55c6f92.lg.png

A parte inicial da URL vai ficar `http://meubucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/categories/images` e você pode colocar este valor em algum arquivo de configuração, caso você precise mudar depois ou você tenha mais de um ambiente dessa aplicação executando (ex: Produção x Integração).

Se você tiver certeza que o `id` do registro nunca muda, você pode até utilizá-lo no lugar do GUID, mas acho mais tranquilo usando o GUID.

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado pela resposta. Eu não entendi muito esse esquema do GUID, mas pelo que eu entendi da tabela, você salvaria somente o nome da imagem, depois usaria a url padrão do bucket e só iria mudar o nome do arquivo, e assim vc poderia acessar qualquer uma das versões? (original, sm, md, lg)

Comment: E como você saberia o formato da imagem? Jpg, Png.. Eu gostei muito dessa ideia, mas talvez n seria mais interessante salvar duas colunas, uma com a URI (caminho e nome do arquivo sem extensão do arquivo), e outra coluna só com a extensão do arquivo?

Comment: O GUID (essa string aleatória) é garantido ser diferente para cada registro. Não sei de onde seus arquivos vêm por isso imaginei a possibilidade de alguns terem o mesmo nome. Gerar um GUID (UUID) para cada registro é uma maneira de solucionar esse problema. Quanto à extensão do arquivo, se você puder padronizar e converter todas as imagens para JPEG ou PNG seria melhor. Se não for possível, então você pode guardar o nome da versão original `xxxxx.original.jpg` e manipular o nome para conseguir os outros tamanhos.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, mas a printscreen da tabela que eu coloquei não resolve? No caso eu trocaria o "image_url" para "image_key", que nem o do seu exemplo. Não daria certo?

Comment: Ah, obs: A geração do nome do arquivo eu uso uma função do PHP uniqid() que cria um nome baseado no timestamp atual, então nunca vai se repetir.

Comment: Desde que você tenha certeza que os arquivos nunca terão o mesmo nome, então você pode deixar o GUID de lado e usar o próprio nome do arquivo. Como você disse, renomeando o campo para `image_key`.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pelas dicas! Marcarei como resposta. Irei seguir suas sugestões em meu app.